# HDD shows up as CDFS, can't format

Tags: windows, external-hard-drive, format

Edit: Forgot to mention that it worked fine the first time I plugged it in (plugged it in to my Macbook Pro). I formatted the external HDD with Mac OS Extended (Journaled) and it all went fine. Then I transfered some files over to the external HDD. After the transfer was completed my Mac wouldn't read the external HDD, so I plugged it in to my Windows and had the same problem (which is where I'm still stuck today).

I bought a 2TB HDD (from Eaget). The problem is that I can't format it since it shows up as CDFS. I've tried diskpart, disk management etc but nothing works. Even tried using ChipGenius and this is all there is to find:

---

"Description: [J:][G:]USB Mass Storage Device(Generic/Generic HDD/HDD)
Device Type:        Mass Storage Device

Protocal Version: USB 2.10 <- Hint: This device can run faster when plugged to a USB3.0 port
Current Speed: High Speed
Max Current: 2mA

USB Device ID: VID = 2537 PID = 1068
Serial Number: 1123456789ABCD1

Device Vendor: EAGET
Device Name: HDD
Device Revision: 0100

Manufacturer: Generic/Generic
Product Model: HDD/HDD
Product Revision: 0/0

Controller Part-Number: Unknown"

---

Disk management (screenshot):

[image]

Disk properties (screenshot):

[image]

Is there anything else I can do?

I have Windows 7.

Comment: The drive letters there don't match at all. In the disk management the drive is E: and in the properties F:. Did you already try to remove the whole partition via disk management?

Comment: @Elias Look more closely at the top pane of the Disk Management window. You'll see the F: volume there with a size of 1 MB.

Comment: Ah yes, I didn't see it as it was only 1MB. Very odd to say the least. Are there files from eaget contained in the cdfs mount? Some manufacturers provide their own tools in a ROM setup like this.

Comment: @Erik Löfberg: Are you sure the drive is getting enough power? Is the E:\ volume from an internal drive? It would help if you gave more information about the model you are using and what other drives you have installed.

Comment: @Elias Yes there are, but just an exe-file to unlock the encryption and a dll-file. When I execute the exe-file and type in the password the "CD Drive (G:) shows up.

Comment: @JamesP Yes the E:\ volume is from my internal hard drive. And the full name of the external hard drive I've got problems with is Eaget G20 2TB HDD.

Comment: It sounds like there is some feature where the manufacturer supplied program mounts the drive only when you have provided the password, but the mounting goes wrong, producing the second CD drive.

Comment: You need to include in your question which drives are internal and which appear when you connect the external drive.

Comment: @LawrenceC Yeah sorry I forgot that, all drives are internal except the F:\ and the G:\ which shows up when I connect my external Eaget HDD,

Comment: What 3rd party software do you have on the PC to read HFS+ partitions? ...and where did the encryption come from? You never mentioned it until comments. What encryption did you use, on which platform? Right now it seems you have a drive that failed on a Mac... then you made things worse by plugging it into a PC that wouldn't know what it was anyway...

Comment: @ErikLöfberg: From your post it looks like you are connecting the hard drive to a USB 2.0 port? Without a Y cable it likely won't get enough power. The F: drive you are seeing could be coming from a separate flash chip so the actual hard drive itself may not even be powering up. You should try it on a USB 3.0 port to rule this out.